# Answer to the Hyperledger Components

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

[image]

1. What is 1. and 8. and why they are using the same Connection name? Why it is required or what does it convey?
2. What are these two cards i.e. 2,3 and why they are required? Can't we have single of these?
3. What and why are these two UserId i.e. 4,5? When are are going to use them? Can't we have single of these?
4. Again Business network i.e. 6,7. What and why first is NONE and Second is tutorial-network?
5. Why 13. is not enabled and 14. is enabled.
6. What is the use of redundant network with same application deployed on two Organisation?
   Source:
   Deploying a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric (multiple organizations)
   https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playground is showing you all the cards in your card store that you used when going through the byfn tutorial. You have acted as 2 different organisations on a single machine (however in the real world you are only likely to have cards for a single organisation). Also Playground can have issues working with a multi-organisation fabric network, such as byfn, around deploying/updating business networks, so it's use with these fabrics is not recommended.

1) Connection Profiles in a network card represent the fabric you want to communicate with. Connection profiles have a name and it is this name that you are seeing. You have 2 sections with the same name because with BYFN you are pretending to be 2 organisations on the same machine and the connection profiles are different between the 2 organisations but have the same name.

2,3) The first card represents a fabric network card and has the name `PeerAdmin` (used for doing fabric level interaction such as deploying a business network) The second card represents a business network card for interacting with the business network as the userid shown. They are 2 different cards that provide different types of access.

4) A fabric network card doesn't connect to a business network, this is why it shows `NONE`. The other one is the name of the business network that the card will connect you to.

5) 13 is not enabled because a fabric network card can never connect to a business network, whereas 14, because it is a business network card can connect to a business network.

6) don't understand the question.

Comment: Thank you for answering @david_k.

Comment: 1. As in my case both 2 Org are on same machine, why they are sharing the same Assets, participant etc. ? [Note: I have added participants in only one ORG1, but same participants are visible in ORG2]

Comment: [Snapshot Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z-QGTBIDSoWR74gPyLnCiu_8Bez2rK-L)